# SqlDependency Slow performance

Tags: c#, sqldependency

I use query notification of `SqlDependency` and here's the scenario:

I have a small table with 100 records but quite large data inside these records

Here's the code:

```
private void AutoUpdate()
{
    SqlDependency.Stop(connectionstring);
    SqlDependency.Start(connectionstring);

    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = @"Select [Number], [Creation date],[Createdby], [Approved]  from  [dbo].[MyTable] Order By Number";

            dt = new DataTable();
            cmd.Notification = null; 
            SqlDependency dep = new SqlDependency(cmd); 
            dep.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dep_OnChange); 
            cn.Open(); 

            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                dt.Load(dr);
            }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
    } 
}
```

and for the `OnChange` event I use the following code

```
private void dep_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{ 
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        dataGridView1.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(AutoUpdate)); 
    }
    else
    { 
        AutoUpdate(); 
    }

    SqlDependency dep = sender as SqlDependency;
    dep.OnChange -= new OnChangeEventHandler(dep_OnChange);
}
```

I also use the `CellValueChanged` event to trigger if the user changes any value in my Datagridview

The problem is: when the user changes the value of one cell, it updates the database and then fires the `OnChange` event which cause to reload all the datatable with all records

Imagine that the user wants to fill the `NUMBER` field with the value '0' for the first 50 record

The user will simply press down arrow then the key 0 on keyboard continuously, and that will cause a huge amount of data to be sent and received, because the application will receive the datatable from the database after every press, and while trying this I experienced a very slow performance

Is there a better approach to implement query notification?

Is there a way to make the `OnChange` event works only on the affected row? not the whole table?

Comment: Instead of updating the database after every change using OnChanged events, you should rather have an event e.g. an 'Update Database' button or update on closing the application that goes through and does all database updates in a batch.  Constantly talking to the database is very noisy and leads to slow performance which you have encountered.

Comment: @Saggio it's a multi-user application... other users has to see the changes in the same time, concurrency is highly important in my application

Comment: Calling SqlDependency.Start/Stop probably doesn't exactly help performance.; SQL Dependency won't tell you what data changed. Maybe, you can stop it from pulling data by just selecting `count(*)`. Implement the change tracking using triggers. Have triggers insert information about changes to some other table. Change Tracking would work as well but it has a delay. Or better yet, have the app insert the change tracking info instead of using triggers.

Comment: @usr first: do you think calling SqlDependency.Start when the application starts and calling SqlDependency.Stop when the application exits is going to help performance? and way I'm giving it a try
secondly,I've no idea what's change tracking or how to implement it, I'm gonna search for it and try to see the different, if you have some quick like I'd be grateful